# Setting "oscif" to false, or omitting the dev_purchase_params:{"oscif":true} in FB.ui call still displays prices in local currency

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-credits

According to the docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/pay/

> dev_purchase_params - Configures whether the Pay Dialog displays
>   prices in local currency (e.g. USD). If {'oscif': true} is provided
>   using the JavaScript SDK, the Pay Dialog displays prices in local
>   currency.

No matter what I do with oscif, whether setting it to false or omitting it completely, I'm still getting this in the Facebook pay dialog:

> Price:    $0.10 USD (1 Credit)

Instead of this:

> Price:    1 Credit ($0.10 USD)

Is there something else going on that I am not aware of? *Seems* like a bug, but I know never to assume this.

I appreciate any help on this!

Comment: LOL for me its the other way around :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have missed the thing that fb is going to scrap the fb credit and it will be only local currency going ahead.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/local_currency_faq/

Comment: Precognition isn't included as part of my primary skill set. :)